# What is the equivalent in English for 喷子？

Tags: meaning, internet-slang

This expression is not the conventional one found in a normal dictionary, but in a large number of posts online. In my guess, it means somebody who is unsatisfied with the real world, right? I am not sure. Perhaps you can share your understanding of it.

Comment: bkrs （normal dictionary）3) инт. жарг. тролль (лицо, провоцирующее эмоциональную перепалку в интернете) Internet jargon, troll (individual provoking emotional squabbling on the Internet)

Answer (score 5):

> troll

One who posts a deliberately provocative message to a newsgroup or message board with the intention of causing maximum disruption and argument

by Alien Entity September 22, 2002

Source: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=troll

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it means "hater"

喷子 in Chinese means those people who always swear and curse others, call names

Answer (score -3):

"噴子" is a nick name,means "Gun"!
The reason is when you shoot with a gun,The gun always splay the bullet!